# matplotlib pyplot - how to combine multiple y-axis and multiple plots

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, subplot, multiple-axes

I need to plot a collection of different plots whis at least two different y-axis each.

I managed to solve each task singularly:

**1st: A collection of different plots:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a1 = np.random.randint(0,10,(6,2))
a2 = np.random.randint(0,10,(6,2)) * 10
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack([a1,a2]), columns = list('abcd'))

plt.subplot(1,2,1)
plt.plot(df.index,df.a,'-b')
plt.plot(df.index,df.c,'-g')

plt.subplot(1,2,2)
plt.plot(df.index,df.b,'-b')
plt.plot(df.index,df.d,'-g')
```

[image]

**2nd: Plots whis at least two different y-axis:**

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax2 = ax.twinx()

ax.plot(df.index,df.a,'-b')
ax2.plot(df.index,df.c,'-g')
```

[image]

But all my attempts to combine this both things failed.  Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: What does it mean when everything fails? Can you describe your desired output?

Comment: @r-beginners I want the multiple plots like in the first picture. But with the green graph plotted on the base of a second y-axis on the right of the plot like in the 2nd picture.

The the first plot of the first picture shall be replaced by the plot of the second picture.

Comment: I still don't fully understand, but is the shape you are looking for a multiple graph with two axes each?

Comment: @r-beginners yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up two axes for each subplot.

```
ax0 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax1 = ax0.twinx()
ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
ax3 = ax2.twinx()
```

**Full Code**

```
fig = plt.figure()
fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)
ax0 = plt.subplot(1,2,1)
ax1 = ax0.twinx()
ax0.plot(df.index,df.a,'-b')
ax1.plot(df.index,df.c,'-g')

ax2 = plt.subplot(1,2,2)
ax3 = ax2.twinx()
ax2.plot(df.index,df.b,'-b')
ax3.plot(df.index,df.d,'-g')

plt.show()
```

[image]